# Salesforce flows picklist with blank option and mandatory and validation

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows, sales-cloud

1. I need to make a picklist mandatory in flows. Please help me to know what i might be doing wrong.

I have a picklist element in flow and on-screen load the picklist field was getting defaulted to the first value of picklist even though I have not added a default value. so I have added a blank choice set so that the field value will be set to blank by default. Even then the required validation is not coming while coming to the next screen. What I might be doing wrong. Please help me to correct.

2. I need to default the picklist entry to a field value from another record(text field) if the value is existing in global picklist. Is there a way to do the validation as the picklist by default do not have any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to make a picklist value dynamic based on the field value of another record, use the dynamic field variable in the choice.

Add this choice in the picklist and select it as a default.

[image]
[image]

Now, since there isn't a 'Validate Input' option for picklists, any validation for picklist values can be added in the Decision after the screen. The user can be redirected to an error screen if the selected picklist value doesn't meet the required criteria.

In the example below, a user is redirected to an error screen if he selects the picklist option 'Please Select a Value' and clicks on Next. Also, in the error screen, the Next button is removed. This makes the user select a value other than 'Please Select a Value' in order to proceed with the next steps in the flow.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Prakhar for the detailed steps it really helps. Is there any way to validate against a list of picklist list values? We have a requirement to populate the picklist value from quote records, but the field in the quote is text and might not be a value available in the picklist option(picklist values are pulled from a global picklist), so is there a way to compare against all the picklist options?

Answer (score 2):

The [Quick Choice community extension](https://unofficialsf.com/quick-choice-improved-picklists-and-radio-buttons-for-flow/) supports Required and Default values for picklists.